# ¿Por qué Activate.ps1 me está causando problemas?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

Traté de crear mi primera API con FastAPI. Creé el entorno virtual para la aplicación, pero me encuentro con este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En caso de que sea un error muy boludo, sepan entender, es la primera vez que hago algo así, y estoy acá para mejorar jajaja.

Tan solo el código que puse es este:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def inicio():
    return "Hola mundo"
```

Comment: Por defecto Windows bloquea la ejecución de scripts de PowerShell. Puedes [reactivarla](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+habilitar+ejecucion+de+scripts) o ejecutar el otro archivo, `Activate.bat`

Comment: Gracias! Sirvió, ahí me dejó de saltar ese error.